# Delete all files using gulp except once that match pattern

Tags: gulp

My src folder contains both *.js files and *.min.js files. I just need to delete all files leaving *.min.js files intact using gulp. I tried this

```
return del.sync([
            'js/**/*',
            '!js/**/*.min.js']);
```

But this deletes all files in the src folder how do I proceed. considering that the src folder also contains other formats other than js